# The module "gbda_aut.dll" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80070005

Tags: regsvr32

I am trying to connect the Matrikon OPC Server with python, for this i have to register the OPC automation wrapper ( gbda_aut.dll ) by typing this in the command line:

```
C:\OpenOPC37\lib>regsvr32 gbda_aut.dll
```

but i am encountring the error:

```
---------------------------
RegSvr32
---------------------------
The module "gbda_aut.dll" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80070005.

For more information about this problem, search online using the error code as a search term.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```